# command not found: import python

Tags: python

I am using the python 3.9 in mac. recently I have install the pip, such as the numpy, when I input"import numpy", it always remind me that "zsh:command not found: import"
And I have tried the method , write"#!/usr/bin/env python3" on the first line(not in the terminal)
but it still couldn't work
So could anyone help me ,thanks a lot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/644a8.png)

Comment: Uh... why are you running a file with only a shebang and then writing import in the terminal itself? Either write your whole code in the file or run python console and then import. Those two don't mix

Comment: You're typing that in the shell. You need to be typing it into your python script file or into a python interpreter. Please follow a tutorial on getting started with Python, here are some recommendations: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial website.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to import numpy in the terminal itself, which will not work.

Try this:

```
$ python3
>> import numpy as np
```